# Dialer app that allow connection (dialing, ringing, busy) sounds be disabled? (might be useful for auto dialing)

Tags: android, phone

I wanted to use redialing app and found out when actual dial goes through, dialing sounds are produced (and of all apps I've tried all use other app to actually dial - hence my bundled dialer on the phone).

I've found no option to disable connection sounds on my Android device. Web search finds links to disabling dialing keypad tones. As I understand dialer app knows when call was answered, so seems possible to disable sounds before that. Are there any dialer apps that have that option?